# Why mysql does not trim whitespace from the beginning and end of the connection url

Tags: mysql, database, connection-pooling

If you use a database connection url with whitespace at the beginning and end of url, connecting will be failed.
So why the database connection pool framework(or the database like mysql, oracle) does not trim whitespace from the beginning and end of the connection url by default.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it?

Most things only happen explicit, not implicit. This is one of them.

The application programmer is supposed to supply its URLs right. If he or she doesn't, it's their responsibility to trim the string.